# What do I do when all my bosses are inept?

Tags: management

Every BOSS I had was inept ? How do I change this ?

Comment: Become your own boss?

Comment: Apply for their job - you should get it easily.

Comment: @Kilisi What makes you think the OP isn't inept too?

Comment: Write better questions? This is very vague and will most likely get downvoted. Or receive sarcastic (but funny) comments. Please look at existing questions for inspiration. You might even find some good tips in already existing questions. This is not a rant forum. Please take some effort to write a good specific (!) question.

Comment: **Every BOSS I had was inept ? How do I change this?** - Become the boss.

Comment: I don't think that'll help lol.  It's just then, OP will have no one to blame but themselves :)

Comment: See the Peter Principle, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_principle, and find an organization where the final state of universal incompetence has not yet bee reached...

Answer (score 7):

There's an old phrase that, although it applies to romantic relationships, it's applicable here:

"If you think all your Exs are toxic, then maybe it's you who are Toxic"

Comment: There is also the story of the soldier who noticed that he was the only in his platoon to be marching with the right pace

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options:

- all your bosses were inept.
  Then you should work on your interview skills.
  Job interviews are a 2 way street, it's your job to find out if you like the job. If you only get accepted for jobs with inept bosses, work on your skills, so you get the other kind.
- your behaviour or your perception turns your boss inept.

  - Do you have unrealistic expectations? Learn what you can realistically expect and what you can't.
  - Do you handle your relation with your boss badly? Then work on your social skills.